# QuickStart basic layout/template for web development?

Tags: templates

I'm looking for a quick start or template, or something, to get a web site's basic layout done quickly and looking fairly professional, and then let me do the coding.  I don't want a CMS, as this is for a highly customised reporting application, but I need something like frame header and two columns and frame footer.  I can design the pretty reports for the wide right hand column myself, as the left hand column menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like YUI Grids CSS?

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/

or Blueprint CSS?

http://www.blueprintcss.org/

Or CSS boilerplate?

http://code.google.com/p/css-boilerplate/

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [BluePrint CSS framework](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) or check out the [CSS Templates](http://www.freecsstemplates.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what language you're using, but if it's Java, [Appfuse](http://appfuse.org/) is a really great tool for creating an entire (skeleton) web application project from a configurable template. This skeleton includes an initial HTML/CSS/Javascript UI that includes common elements such as a login page, an "add user" page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your IDE, Eric Meyer wrote a program called [CSS Sculptor](http://www.webassist.com/professional/products/productdetails.asp?PID=253) that you can use to quickly develop standards-based layouts. I've used it, and it's great.

Comment: It looks like you need to have Dreamweaver installed to use this is that right?

Comment: It's also available for Expression Web.